# C# websocket firehose and threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, websocket

I have a c# websocket client. When I receive a message, the processing is likely going to take more time than it will take to receive a new message. Essentially, I'd like to run single threaded and simply ignore the in-between messages so I don't get bogged down and behind. The .net ecosystem has so many options and objects for managing threading, I'd like to hear some opinions about the best way to architect this solution.

Comment: You can put your messages in a queue (in memory or an external service), then create a few worker or even apps to process messages in multiple threads. This way you have full control. If you're working on a single app, I suggest using the Channels.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks

Comment: @AliRezaSabouri I mentioned in the question that I don't need to process every message. I know it sounds weird, but I'd like to run single-threaded and ignore messages that come in while that single thread is processing.

Comment: ow! In that case, just create a flag like `isProcessing = true` and until this is not false, ignore all incoming messages. I don't get what are you looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to me why you need this, but if I understand correctly, a simple flag can help.

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class WebSocketClient
{
    private readonly ClientWebSocket socket;
    private bool isProcessing = false;

    public WebSocketClient()
    {
        socket = new ClientWebSocket();
    }

    public async Task ConnectAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        await socket.ConnectAsync(uri, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync()
    {
        while (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
            if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
            {
                string message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, result.Count);
                if (!isProcessing)
                {
                    _ = ProcessMessageAsync(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessMessageAsync(string message)
    {
        isProcessing = true;
        // Your message processing logic here
        await Task.Delay(2000); // Simulate a time-consuming operation
        Console.WriteLine($"Processed message: {message}");
        isProcessing = false;
    }
}
```